# Does Firestore querying always work best when documents are organized by type in a single collection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am planning my database structure for one of my projects and keep seeing that Firestore querying works best when all of your documents of similar type are in one collection such as this

```
[Posts]      [Users] 
- id1        - uid1            
   :doc1        :doc1
- id2        - uid2
   :doc2        :doc2
```

However, is this always best for querying even if one collection has lets say 1 million documents? 
In my current project, I anticipate several "post" documents and am wondering if it would be best to organize them in sub-collections based on year to make sure a certain collection won't be overfilled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the collection doesn't matter at all.  Firestore scales massively, and queries will not slow down as a collection grows.  If you need all your documents to be in a single collection for effective querying, then just do that.  If you need billions of document in a collection, that is no problem.